# What are strategies for bridging Google Cloud with AWS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, google-cloud-platform

Let's say a company has an application with a database hosted on AWS and also has a read replica on AWS. Then that same company wants to build out a data analytics infrastructure in Google Cloud -- to take advantage of data analysis and ML services in Google Cloud.

Is it necessary to create an additional read replica within the Google Cloud context? If not, is there an alternative strategy that is frequently used in this context to bridge the two cloud services?

Comment: That's tough to answer without more specifics, but if you're trying to bridge the gap between the providers, try not to duplicate infrastructure. Use one provider as your main source of IaaS and use the other's SaaS and PaaS offerings since they're more "portable". What type of database are you using on AWS and what sort of analytics are you hoping to get with GCP?

Answer (score 1):

While services like Amazon Relational Database Service (RDS) provides read-replica capabilities, it is only between managed database instances on AWS.

If you are replicating a database between providers, then you are probably running the database yourself on virtual machines rather than using a managed service. This means the databases appear just like any resource on the Internet, so you can connect them exactly the way you would connect two resources across the internet. However, you **would be responsible for managing, monitoring, deploying, etc.** This takes away from much of the benefit of using cloud services.

Replicating between storage services like Amazon S3 would be easier since it is just raw data rather than a running database. Also, Big Data is normally stored in raw format rather than being loaded into a database.

If the existing infrastructure is on a cloud provider, then try to perform the remaining activities on the same cloud provider.